# Prevent popup from pausing powershell script

Tags: powershell

I know that by design the popup pauses the script until the user presses OK or closes it.

However, i'm trying to display something to a user in this popup, for example `WARNING - STRING XYZ WAS DETECTED`, while the script still continues.

Is it possible to prevent that popup from pausing the script?

```
$test = (Get-Process -Name Win*).ProcessName 
$message_popup = (New-Object -COM Wscript.Shell).Popup(($test -join "`r`n"), 0, "Title", "48")

write-host "rest of script..."
```

Comment: Wscript call within Powershell makes little sense. What are you [trying to achieve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: The actual case is showing a lot of data in a gridview, and i want the popup to alert the user if a certain string is detected in all that data (I would prefer highlighting in out-gridview but it's not possible). I don't want the popup to prevent the gridview from showing since it pauses the script. Or if i put the popup after the gridview, the user has to close the gridview first to see the popup. Am I being clear enough? PS.: I know i could use DataGridView for highlighting but then i lose some nice features Out-Gridview has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out what I needed was the JOB cmdlet, this works perfectly. Just make sure to pass your desired variable in the -ArgumentList and use it as $args in the job scriptblock!

```
$test = (Get-Process -Name Win*).ProcessName 


  Start-Job -ArgumentList $test -ScriptBlock {
  (New-Object -COM Wscript.Shell).Popup(($args[0] -join "`r`n"), 0, "Title", "48")
  } | Out-Null



write-host "rest of script..."
```